# Visual Studio CrtDumpMemoryLeaks Broken?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

I seem to be having issues with the Visual Studios build in memory leak detection tools.
No matter what I do, it is always detecting a memory leak.

Here I have a basic C++ main, with the memory leak detection enabled (as per MSDN).

```
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>

int main (){

    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks ();
    return 0;
}
```

For reasons unknown, it says there is a memory leak.

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{142} normal block at 0x0000005934F90660, 16 bytes long.
Data: < 3"             > C8 33 22 DC F6 7F 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
Object dump complete.
```

Has anyone else experienced this?
Does anyone know what causes this?

P.S I am using Visual Studio 2013, but I have also experienced this in 2012 and 2010.

Comment: That seems odd, but so does not setting the report mode. I'm curious if the same thing happens if you set a check-point, then report immediately since the check-point. (I'd check it myself, but I don't have a Windows-with-VS box handy.

Answer (score -1):

The "_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks ();" will show the state of memory as it is executed, i.e. you have a memory block allocated just now.

```
int main (){
    std::string tmp("Hello");
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks ();  //this will show you have a memory leak (in the string object)
    return 0;
}
```

Use

```
int main (){
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
    std::string tmp("Hello");
    return 0;
}
```

and you will find the debug output in the "output" window after the program exit. There is no memory leak since the system has deleted the string object.

If you also include

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#define new new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )  
#endif
```

first in all your code files (or first i a common .h file) you will get the place where the offending memory was allocated.

This will NOT work if you have redefined the new operator.